# Android firestore Retrieve Data map

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

How to retrieve the data in nested object? Im able to get all the data in document but fail to retrieve the nested object, **Just want to retrieve all the data under usr_card-card1,card2 into array or map**

```
userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

                DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userid);
                documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document.exists()) {
                                String usr_name = "usr_name",usr_email="usr_email";
                                String name = document.getString(usr_name);
                                String email = document.getString(usr_email);

                                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about what your specific goal is, and what isn't working the way you expect.  You have several fields and objects in the document shown here - what do you need out of it?

Comment: Do you have a POJO class for your user object? Basically a class that contains all those fields? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo no, i did not create that

Comment: If you intend to do that, this article, **[How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)** will help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map type fields in Firestore documents show up as Map type objects in Java.

```
Map<String, Object> usr_card = (Map<String, Object) document.get("usr_card");
```

You can work with the returned Map exactly as you would any other Map.

Comment: Map<String, Object> usr_card = (Map<String, Object) document.get("usr_card");  is works to retrieve item under "usr_card", is that possible to retrieve item (card_num,card_exp,card_cvc) by using loop? both ”card1” and ”card2”.Thanks

Comment: For example: put card1 and card 2 "card_num" into array or map